# How do I fix when I join everybody else gets kicked and Minecraft crashes when I join my Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I made a crazy craft 3 server and the server was fine until when I clicked on the fire in the inventory section, Minecraft crashed and all the other people that were playing got kicked from the server. So when the other people joined back it was fine. It only crashes when I join.

Comment: does the issue occur on a fully vanilla server

Comment: Could be that technically you are not supposed to have that item in an inventory. Try deleting your player data for that server. NOTE: You will lose all of the stuff you had in your inventory and all progress in Advancements.

Comment: @Potterton merely not supposed to have an item shouldn't cause that, something else is wrong

Comment: @Penguin I agree, I just thought maybe try that before anything else drastic. I am not the best at server issues, so I am not the guy to ask....

Comment: @potterton yeah honestly I'm not either xD